# Spark mllib - NaiveBayes weightcol parameter influence and format

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am currently trying several algorithm on my data to determine which is the best. Also I look at how I can customize said algorithm and use the `CrossValidator` object to test those parameters.

I got stuck on `NaiveBayes` and the `WeightCol` parameter.

I could not find any information on it, how it works and how to set it.
Comment in the code say : "If this is not set or empty, we treat all instance weights as 1.0" and so I thought I could use value like "mycolumn=1.0,myothercol=2.0" but whatever I tried I always have an error in return.

The only time I don't have an error is if a use "mycolumn" as value for example but i have no idea what is the effect of that.

If anyone know of to use this parameter I would be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`weight` `Param` should a double and is used to determine importance of the samples for example to correct for skewed labels distribution.

Let's say you have data like this:

```scala
val data = spark.read.format("libsvm").load("data/mllib/sample_libsvm_data.txt")

val skewed = data
  .where($"label" === 0.0).limit(5)
  .union(data.where($"label" === 1.0))

skewed.groupBy($"label").count.show
```

```
+-----+-----+
|label|count|
+-----+-----+
|  0.0|    5|
|  1.0|   57|
+-----+-----+
```

We can add higher weight to records with `label` equal 0.0:

```scala
val weighted = skewed
  .withColumn("weight", when($"label" === 0.0, 1.0).otherwise(0.1))

val weightedModel = new NaiveBayes().setWeightCol("weight").fit(weighted)

weightedModel.transform(weighted.where($"label" === 0.0)).show
```

```
+-----+--------------------+------+--------------------+-----------+----------+
|label|            features|weight|       rawPrediction|probability|prediction|
+-----+--------------------+------+--------------------+-----------+----------+
|  0.0|(692,[127,128,129...|   1.0|[-165013.81130787...|  [1.0,0.0]|       0.0|
|  0.0|(692,[129,130,131...|   1.0|[-191959.02863649...|  [1.0,0.0]|       0.0|
|  0.0|(692,[154,155,156...|   1.0|[-201850.30335886...|  [1.0,0.0]|       0.0|
|  0.0|(692,[127,128,129...|   1.0|[-202315.73236242...|  [1.0,0.0]|       0.0|
|  0.0|(692,[153,154,155...|   1.0|[-258710.53340756...|  [1.0,0.0]|       0.0|
+-----+--------------------+------+--------------------+-----------+----------+
```

To scale feature vectors you can use [`ElementwiseProduct`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#elementwiseproduct).